# How to save data-from-parent-to-child-tables-based-on-entities-in-spring-jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a table master table user ,topics table and comments table
where in for a single topic there can be multiple comments

user table will be already populated.
I will get a post request to save the topic with structure like below

```
{  
   "topicId":"T001",
   "title":"stackoverflow",
   "commentBeans":[  
      {  
"comment":"developer platform"
      },

      {  
"comment":"developer communtiy"
      }
   ]
}
```

Frameworks used:
spring boot
JPA
DB : postgressql

I am able to save the data the traditional way (i.e get the request and save topic bean first. get the primarykey from saved entity and loop the list of commentbean where user num will be set dynamically by another get service and save them)

I wanted to know if there is anyway to save the data with single save query.

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="user")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_num")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long userNum;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "topics")
public class TopicBean implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "topic_num")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long topicNum;

    @Column(name = "topicId")
    private String topicId;
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="topicBean")
    private List<CommentBean> commentBeans;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class CommentBean implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CommentBeanKey key;


    @Column(name = "comment")
    private string comment;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="topic_num")
    private TopicBean topicBean;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_num")
    private TopicBean topicBean;

}

@Embeddable
public class CommentBeanKey implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5889249943605061539L;

    @Column(name ="topic_num")
    private Long topicNum;

    @Column(name ="user_num")
    private Long userNum;


}
```

I saw the below link and am little worried if am doing the wrong way. any help is appreciated.

https://thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-an-entity-to-multiple-tables/

Comment: What you need is cascading operations... @OneToMany(mappedBy="topicBean", cascade = CascadeType.ALL).
Take a look at the different types to refine it.

Comment: Am trying to insert the primary key of topic table in comment table , am getting constraint violation exception since the primary key is null while insertion.

Comment: cascadeType.ALL should take care of that issue for you. Have you tried that?

Comment: I tried and am getting constraint violation exception since the primary key of topic table is going as null in comments table

Comment: Hello @Vignesh_A, I have created one sample for you, please change code according to it and if any issue is there let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int parentId;
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent",fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Child> child = new ArrayList<Child>();
}
```

**Child.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int childId;
    private String account;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = Parent.class)
    @JoinColumn(name="parentId", referencedColumnName = "parentId", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

**Controller.java**

```
//save Child with Parent at same 
    @PostMapping(value = "/onetomany")
    public String OneToMany(@RequestBody Parent parent)
    {
        System.out.println("Parent: "+parent.toString());
        for (Child child : parent.getChild()) {
            child.setParent(parent);
        }

        parent.setChild(parent.getChild());
        parentRepository.save(parent);
        return "saved";

         /*{
            "name":"Romil",
            "child":[
               {"account":"1"},
               {"account":"2"}
             ]
         }*/
    }

        //save Child with Parent's ID
        @PostMapping(value = "/onetomanyPID")
        public String OneToMany(@RequestBody Child child)
        {
            child.setParent(child.getParent());
            childRepository.save(child);
            return "saved";

            /*{
            "account":"3",
             "parent":{
                 "parentId":"1",
                  "name":"Romil"
              }
            }*/
        }
```

Comment: Patel, need some clarification.
1) Is it possible to save parent's autogenerated primary key in child table as foreign key during parent table insertion. actually I tried inserting data the way you said but I am getting parentId as null in the exception.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. For above controller it is first case. Make sure you set the parent for each child (for loop here) and set the child after that as parent.setChild(..).

Comment: Please share the related code where you perform save operation with Json Input

Comment: Hello, @Vignesh_A Please accept and upvote the answer if it was helpful

Comment: Hi Patel, am still not able to solve the issue. my child object has composite primary key and i assume your solutions works only for single primary key? correct me if am wrong. btw will share the github link in next couple of days.